# Rails parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I am trying to create a join between two objects and I am confused about pasing parameters. I have a form that submits this:

```
 assign_service_url([abs_id: abstractor.id, serv_id: service.id]),
```

I would think that the following would work but it doesn't

```
 @abstractor = Abstractor.find(params[:abs_id]) 
 @service = Service.find(params[:serv_id])
```

Here is what I get in my console:

```
params[:id]
=> "abs_id=2&serv_id=1"
>> params[:abs_id]
=> nil
>> params[:abs]
=> nil
>> params[:id]
=> "abs_id=2&serv_id=1"
>> params
=> {"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"WwSfk8rw8PfWA8FNLZs+6SUZBEgCW7ZHF2BuPxLxzsXfwRQWmfr7tfDBH/nBCytuYs6GjDdBOeGzVeb9Ph399A==",
"controller"=>"services", "action"=>"assign", "id"=>"abs_id=2&serv_id=1"}
```

I could parse the string but it seems that it should be much easier. I think I am missing something

How do I make this work?

Comment: are you using the helper methods to build the form?

Comment: That `assign_service_url` with an array argument is odd.  What does your route for that url look like?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `Hash` instead of an array, like this:

```
assign_service_url({abs_id: abstractor.id, serv_id: service.id})
```

Now you will be able to receive `params[:abs_id]` & `params[:serv_id]`

Comment: you forgot to [vote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917105/ruby-arrays-find-the-sums-of-the-diagonals) me.. :D