# Ruby Arrays - Find the sums of the diagonals

Tags: ruby, arrays

Haven't seen this one before, but I was wondering how you can find the sums of both diagonals of a 2D array in Ruby. Say you have a simple array, with 3 rows and 3 columns.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I can break it into groups of three by using

```
array.each_slice(3).to_a
```

Would now be

```
[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]

[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

In this case, the diagonals are

```
1 + 5 + 9 = 15
3 + 5 + 7 = 15
```

So the total sum would be `15 + 15 = 30`

I was thinking I could do something like

```
diagonal_sum = 0
for i in 0..2
  for j in 0..2
    diagonal_sum += array[i][j]
  end
end
```

Comment: j is determined by i and not free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my try :

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sliced = array.each_slice(3).to_a
# As sliced size is 3, I took 2, i.e. 3 - 1
(0..2).map { |i| sliced[i][i] } #=> [1, 5, 9]
(0..2).map { |i| sliced[i][-i-1] } # => [3, 5, 7]
(0..2).map { |i| sliced[i][i] }.reduce :+
# => 15
(0..2).map { |i| sliced[i][-i-1] }.reduce :+
# => 15
```

As per the above *observation* it seems in one iteration you can do solve :

```
left_diagonal, right_diagoal = (0..2).each_with_object([[], []]) do |i, a|
  a[0] << sliced[i][i]
  a[1] << sliced[i][-i-1]
end

left_diagonal.reduce(:+) # => 15
right_diagonal.reduce(:+) # => 15
```

Added, *OOP* style of code :

```
class SquareMatrix
  attr_reader :array, :order

  def initialize array, n
    @array = array.each_slice(n).to_a
    @order = n
  end

  def collect_both_diagonal_elements
    (0...order).collect_concat { |i| [ array[i][i], array[i][-i-1] ] }
  end

  def collect_left_diagonal_elements
    (0...order).collect { |i| array[i][i] }
  end 

  def collect_right_diagonal_elements
    (0...order).collect { |i| array[i][-i-1] }
  end

  def sum_of_diagonal_elements type
    case type
    when :all   then collect_both_diagonal_elements.reduce(0, :+)
    when :right then collect_right_diagonal_elements.reduce(0, :+)
    when :left  then collect_left_diagonal_elements.reduce(0, :+)
    end
  end
end

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sqm   = SquareMatrix.new array, 3
sqm.collect_both_diagonal_elements # => [1, 3, 5, 5, 9, 7]
sqm.sum_of_diagonal_elements :all # => 30
sqm.collect_left_diagonal_elements # => [1, 5, 9]
sqm.sum_of_diagonal_elements :left # => 15
sqm.collect_right_diagonal_elements # => [3, 5, 7]
sqm.sum_of_diagonal_elements :right # => 15
```

Comment: This is a clean answer.

Answer (score 5):

The following is mostly for the academic discussion:

For the main diagonal, you are looking for the "Trace" function which is defined for the "Matrix" class. So the following will work (although it doesn't get you the other diagonal and I wouldn't bet on its efficiency):

```
require 'Matrix'
a = array.each_slice(3).to_a
Matrix[*a].trace
```

To get the other diagonal you have to somehow "flip" the matrix, so the following seems to work (Since the result of `each_slice` is an array of rows, `reverse` reverses the order of the row. Reversing the order of the columns is more difficult):

```
Matrix[*a.reverse].trace
```

Comment: Good answer. (I would have posted the same.) Some minor editing suggestions. 1. "For the main diagonal, you couild use [Matrix#trace](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-trace)". 2. `arr = array.each_slice(3).to_a; Matrix(*arr].trace #=> 15`.  3. "To get the other diagonal, you need to reverse the order of the rows before invoking `trace`: `Matrix[*arr.reverse].trace #=> 15`". No reply req'd as I'll delete this comment when I figure you've seen it.

Comment: Not just an academic discussion--this is the best answer. My first thought was that the Matrix class could come in handy. Asssuming the OP started with a *real* 2D array, the diagonal is simple `Matrix[array].trace`. Unffortunately I don't see a built-in way to mirror an array to get the reverse diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

I totally forgot about #map.with_index ...Thanks to @xlembouras , heres a one-liner

```
first_diagonal = array.map.with_index {|row, i| row[i]} .inject :+
inverted_diagonal = array.map.with_index {|row, i| row[-i-1]} .inject :+
```

It's possible to make it a one-liner:

```
first_diagonal, inverted_diagonal = (array.map.with_index {|row, i| row[i]} .inject :+) , (array.map.with_index {|row, i| row[-i-1]} .inject :+)
```

Original:

Here's a thought, which makes me think it would be great to have a #map_with_index method:

for a first to last diagonal:

```
i = -1
array.map { |row| row[i=i+1] }.inject :+
```

for the last to first diagonal (assuming a square array):

```
i = array.length
array.map { |row| row[i=i-1] }.inject :+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
p a.values_at(0,2,4,4,6,8).inject(&:+) #=> 30
```

Comment: Nice, simple answer. Sometimes the simple answer is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try iterating through the array and keep the values that I need according to the length of the (grouped) array

```
array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

dimension = array.length

array.flatten.map.with_index do |x,i|
  x if [0, dimension - 1].include?(i % dimension)
end.compact.inject(:+)

#=> 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to first apply `slice`:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

We visualize `arr` as:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

n = Math.sqrt(arr.size).round 
  #=> 3
```

For the main diagonal:

```
(0...arr.size).step(n+1).reduce(0) { |t,i| t+arr[i] }
  #=> 15
```

For the off-diagonal:

```
(n-1..arr.size-n).step(n-1).reduce(0) { |t,i| t+arr[i] }
  #=> 15
```

Another example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2
3 4 5 6

n = Math.sqrt(arr.size).round 
  #=> 4

(0...arr.size).step(n+1).reduce(0) { |t,i| t+arr[i] } +
(n-1..arr.size-n).step(n-1).reduce(0) { |t,i| t+arr[i] }
  #=> 14 + 14 => 28
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'Matrix'

arr = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [6, 7, 8]]

diag1 = Matrix[*arr].tr
diag2 = Matrix[*arr.reverse].tr
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def diagonal(array)
 single=array.flatten
 new=[]
 i=array.length-1

 while i < single.length-2
   new << single[i]
   i+=array.length-1
 end
 new.sum
  
    
end



p diagonal([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 9, 8],
]) 


 OUTPUT
 15
That is for finding the sum of right diagonal of a 2D array
```